# Instagram-Node calls keep returning "access code invalid"

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I recently opened a new Instagram account and registered a new client. The information I received back from Instagram included the client_id and the client_secret.

I will only run the script on my machine, and be the sole user of the project, so I don't need any user to "log in". But for some reason, whenever I try to make any calls to the Instagram-Node API, it returns the following error:

```
{ [Error: OAuthAccessTokenException: The access_token provided is invalid.]
  code: 400,
  error_type: 'OAuthAccessTokenException',
  error_message: 'The access_token provided is invalid.',
  retry: [Function] }
```

That's weird to me, because I have an identical setup with an older Instagram account and different credentials, that seem to be working just fine. Then again, that was before November, when Instagram changed some of their [API policies](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/).

I use the Instagram-Node like so:

```
ig.use({
    client_id: "dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2",
    client_secret: "4b0xaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxaxa53c03100e4"
});
```

and make my first call like this:

```
ig.user_media_recent(user.toString(), options,...
```

I tried handling the authentication by rerouting my request through the redirect_uri as shown in the [Instagram-Node](https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node) documentation, but even then, all of my requests are unsigned, so it's not clear to me what I would do with the access_token any way.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is a misunderstanding of the limits of the Sandbox Mode, they essentially make it impossible to look up media from users who are not in your sandbox.

The [documentation here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) says:

> The first point is important and it means that the API behaves as if
>   the only users on Instagram were your sandbox users, and the only
>   media ever posted were the last 20 for each of these users.

I was trying to find media from users who are not in my sandbox, and so I received an error. The reason that my previous credentials weren't affected is because they are still grandfathered into the grace period, June 2016, at which time they will expire as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. If your app is using oauth, you will cause Instagram to spaz out if you pass the client_secret and client_id stuff again. I had to take these out of my code. So I just pass the access_token now.

```
ig.use({ access_token: token });

ig.user_media_recent(config.userid, { count: 20 }, function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
```

Were my equivalant statements.

EDIT: I forget to mention. This is after a cycle of these for those confused:

```
api.authorize_user
api.get_authorization_url
```